# Search functionality is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs search functionality. Normal search functionality is working without any issue. My my requirement is different.

```js
$scope.arrData = [
    "The Community is here",
    "The Community error message" ,
    "This is our country",
    "Error message displayed"
];
```

I will get response from API service. After got teh response ,if I search any record in a search box in random keyword, i will not get any result.

- After getting response, If I search "The Community" in a textbox, I will get response **["The Community is here", "The Community error message"]**
- But, the actual Text is "The Community error message", here if I search "The error message", I am not getting any result. It is empty. The same way if I search from last like, "message error" or "message community", I am not getting any result.
- My need is, If I enter any word randomly, it should search and display the result. For Example "error message" means, it should show **["The Community error message" ,"Error message displayed" ]**  This two result.

```js
$scope.canShow = function (card) {
  if($scope.search){
    return !$scope.search ||
           ($scope.search &&
            card.Tag.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1);
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" class="form-control search-field" ng-model="search">

<div class="object-thumb" ng-repeat="card in value" ng-show="canShow(card)">
   <div class="object-thumb-body">
       <div class="get-object">
          <div class="get-object-wrap">
            <div id="{{ card.objectid }}"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, card.Tag is the field, where i will get the resposne.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem like this way

```
$scope.arrData= [
    "The Community is here",
    "The Community error message" ,
    "This is our country",
    "Error message displayed"
];

let a = $scope.arrData;
var term = $scope.search; // search term (The Community)
var search = new RegExp(term , 'i'); // prepare a regex object
$scope.value = a.filter(function(item){
  return search.test(item)
});
console.log($scope.value); //here your desire output
```

Comment: Hi @Mayank, I am using Qliksense Object. So ES6 will not support. Could you please send in angularjs way.

Comment: @sathishkumar please check, is it okay ?